# VC compiler version for php extensions creation

Tags: php, c, compiler-construction

I've worked with Visual Studio 2008(visual c) to create a php extension, so after writing the c code and compiling the whole project, A dll file has been generated in the debug folder.
I copied this dll file to the php /ext folder ( extensions folder) and I added this line in php.ini

> extension=php_talkphp.dll (php_talkphp.dll is the dll name)

then I restart apache server to initialise php extensions. but an error has occured : and this is the error message:

[image]

I know that this is due to the compiler version, but How can I use the Vc6 version in a VS2008?

thank you

Comment: Maybe My question needs some explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the extensions built with the same compiler as your PHP install.

In this case - you are using an installation of PHP built with Visual C++ 6, which is an incredibly old compiler. Your extension is built with Visual C++ 9.0, which is much newer.

You can not mix extensions and PHP installs built with different VC compilers.

Possible solutions:

- Get the TalkPHP extension built with Visual C++ 6, and build your own with VC6. You probably will have a hard time getting this since it's an unsupported, unavailable compiler.

**or**

- Install a version of PHP built with Visual C++ 9.0. This will introduce different problems however:

  1. You will either need to switch to using IIS or use a version of apache built with Visual C++ 9.0. [Apache Lounge has them](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/).
  2. You will have to install the [Visual C++ 9.0 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en) if you don't already have it.

Comment: thank you for this reply, but isn't it possible to add a VC6 compiler to a VC++ 9??

Comment: @Simo TAQI - You can not mix PHP binaries with extensions built with a different Visual C++ compiler, because they use different and incompatible implementations of Microsoft's C++ library, so if they were to start passing stuff like containers between each other, there would be problems.